# Java convention for if/else if order

Tags: java, coding-standards, conditions, conventions

I have an if/else if structure that on some cases does nothing. From the code I have seen in my career, the "empty" case is normally left out. But when I wrote my code, it just doesn't feel right to leave this case out, but to show it as a real case that simply does nothing. For example, in a case where something is done when a number is below 5 and above 10, but in between nothing is done:

```
int a = 4
if(a < 5) {
  do something
} else if(a >=5 && a <= 10) {
  // do nothing
} else if(a > 10) {
  do something else
}
```

The reason I thought this is a better option is because:

1. The is how I though about the problem in my mind.
2. This shows the reader of the code that I thought of all the possibilities and didn't forget one by mistake.

So I was wondering if this convention is either accepted by the programming community or it is shunned upon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elegant ways to handle if(if else) else](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/122485/elegant-ways-to-handle-ifif-else-else) and of [Are too many if-else statements for validation bad?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/209822/are-too-many-if-else-statements-for-validation-bad)

Comment: In your example it's ok, but in other cases where a is not an int but for instance a property, the mere checking of a multiple times can have sides effects.

Comment: What about if a is less than or equal to zero?  Is this supposed to only handle positive numbers?

Comment: @gnat: Your 'duplicate detector' seems to have malfunctioned here. The only relation between this Q and the two you mentioned as possible duplicates is that they concern if-statements.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I believe these are dupes. And it's interesting how "conveniently" you omit else-statements in your analysis of the questions

Comment: @gnat: Fair enough that you believe them to be duplicates. I don't, but lets agree to disagree on that one. With regard to not mentioning "else-statements", for me the `else` is part and parcel of the `if`. An if-statement may or may not contain an else part (or even an elif part), but I don't consider those to be separate statements.

Comment: I usually "cheat" in this case by putting in a log statement: 'else if (a >=5 && a <= 10) {LOG.debug("Nothing to do, because ...")}'. Keeps the compiler and checkstyle happy *AND* provides a hint to future maintainers that you actually thought about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not simply checking the value of `a` for the sake of it. It probably *means* something.

Thus I would prefer to see:

```
Boolean sell = a < 5;
Boolean buy = a > 10;
Boolean error = a >= 5 & a <= 10;
// or even: 
Boolean error = !sell & !buy;
/* ^ (that's single source principle: if 5 changes to 6 one day, 
 * you don't have to remember to change it in two places) */
```

And then:

```
if (sell) {

} else if (buy) {

} else if (error) {

}
```

Isn't it clearer?

Furthermore, could `a` be **both** less than `5` and greater than `10`??

Rather not, so those `else`s are clearly redundant. (*Unless* you change the value of `a` within one of your `if` blocks, mind you, If you only evaluate `a` once, however - as in my example - you don't have to worry about it).

Hence:

```
Boolean sell = a < 5;
Boolean buy = a > 10;
Boolean error = !sell & !buy;

if (sell) {

} 
if (buy) {

} 
if (error) {
    // handle error
}
```

This is way clearer and more flexible in my opinion - if some conditions are no longer mutually exclusive, as it can happen, you won't need to do much refactoring at all.

Comment: Very interesting idea. Only thing I don't like about it is that it makes the code longer, which makes it "harder" to read. But otherwise it is very elegant.

Comment: @vainolo yes it's longer by three lines, but I think it actually improves the readability (since your conditions are given meaningful names) and so the trade off is worth it. Of course ultimately it comes down to taste

Comment: When the difference in efficiency is negligible as in this case, readability is most important. Simplifying conditionals by extracting and naming their components is a great way to improve readability.

Comment: I like a series of if-else-if-else and virtually always have an else at the end.  Similarly for a switch-statement, I virtually always have a default case.  I think that it's just a good idea to always consider every case, and if a case is "impossible" then have an assert statement there (if not throw an exception), and to be sure to turn on assertions for debugging and for testing.

Answer (score 11):

I would avoid to define the *do nothing* case explicit by giving the intervall. I would use an `else`-branch for that

```
int a = 4
if(a < 5) {
  do something
} else if(a > 10) {
  do something else
} else {
     //This should mean: (a >=5 && a <= 10)
     // do nothing

     // Maybe log something here 
     // or even add an assertion while development to ensure that the 
     // branch is only reached in expected cases:
     assert (a >=5 && a <= 10) : "I expected 'a' to be 5<=a<=10, but a is:"+a;
}
```